# How to switch to TTY2 once by editing GRUB or otherwise

Tags: grub2, tty

I am using both **Xubuntu** and **Kubuntu** **20.04**.

When I edit `grub` and add number **3** at the end of the line starting with `linux`, I start the system in console mode for that one time only. The problem is that the console output is displayed on **TTY2**, whereas the system switches to **TTY1** when using number **3**. Each time I use **3**, I am forced to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> in order to switch to **TTY2**.

Can this switching be made programmatically by adding another command to `grub` or by doing something else so that I don't have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> every time I use console mode?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to login in text mode instead of the display manager login screen? If so, why not just disable the display manager?